# How to have light shine through loaded GLTF model in react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm attempting to make a solar system model using react-three-fiber, but i'm having a hard time getting the sun model to work how i want it to. I currently have a pointLight that goes out from the star, lighting up all the planets that orbit it, however I'm not sure how to get the star itself to light up.

```
return (
    <>
      <mesh ref={meshRef} {...meshProps}>
        <primitive
          scale={scale ? scale : 1}
          object={gltf.scene}
          children-0-castShadow
        />
      </mesh>
      {isStar && (
        <pointLight position={[0, 0, 0]} intensity={500} color="#edd59e" />
      )}
      <OrbitLine radius={initialPosition[0]} />
    </>
  );
```

this component is used to render all the celestial objects, and i have specific cases if the object is a star, here's where i actually put those objects on the canvas

```
function SolarSystem() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <OrbitControls />
      <Stars factor={6} fade speed={0} />
      <ambientLight intensity={1} />
      {/* <pointLight position={[0, 10, 0]} intensity={500} color="#edd59e" /> */}
      <StellarObjectGeometry
        position={[0, 0, 0]}
        isStar={true}
        model={sun.model}
        scale={sun.scale}
      />
      
      {sun.orbiters.map((planet, p_index) => (
        <>
          <StellarObjectGeometry
            position={[(p_index + 1) * 5, 0, (p_index + 1) * 5]}
            key={p_index}
            model={planet.model}
            scale={planet.scale}
          />
          {planet.orbiters.map((moon, m_index) => (
            <StellarObjectGeometry
              key={`${p_index}-${m_index}`}
              position={[
                (p_index + 1) * 5,
                (m_index + 1) * 2,
                (p_index + 1) * 5,
              ]}
              isMoon={true}
              model={moon.model}
              scale={moon.scale}
            />
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

i've tried to add bloom by doing

```
return (
    <>
      {isStar && (
        <EffectComposer>
          <Bloom intensity={3} />
        </EffectComposer>
      )}
      <mesh ref={meshRef} {...meshProps}>
        <primitive
          scale={scale ? scale : 1}
          object={gltf.scene}
          children-0-castShadow
        />
      </mesh>
      {isStar && (
        <pointLight position={[0, 0, 0]} intensity={500} color="#edd59e" />
      )}
      <OrbitLine radius={initialPosition[0]} />
    </>
  );
```

but that was ineffective and i believe it's because bloom only makes brighter that which is already bright, and the star model is not. This is the model i'm using for the star https://poly.pizza/m/1Zo-IZ5W-gR
Any help is appreciated!